# Unable to create an object for DataContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to run the migration in order to create sqlite DB in .net core 6. But getting the following error

> Unable to create an object for DataContext.For different patterns
> supported at design time.

appsettings.json file code

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data source=UrlDB.db"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

DataContext class code

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UrlTbl> UrlTbl { get; set; }
}
```

I also created an extension class just to keep my code clean. and in this class, I have an extension method to addDbConext into services. Here is the code of that class

```
public static class ApplicationServicesExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection _services, IConfiguration _config)
    {
        _services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlite(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
        return _services;
    }
}
```

and I am accessing this extension method in Programme.cs in this way

```
using UrlEntryApp.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
IConfiguration _config=app.Configuration;
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddApplicationServices(_config);
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

Comment: [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: When does the error arise? Is it in the code, or when you run a particular program?

Comment: Seeems your `DataContext(DbContextOptions options)` is incorreect, could you pleeasee try  `DbContextOptions<DataContext>` instead.

Comment: @AnnL. - migration tool must create DbContext for its work, but it can't. There is a link to what needs to be done in the first comment.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - no, it won't help the migration utility to create a DbContext.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your `DataContext` to this:

```cs
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
       Configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        // connect to sql server database
        options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }
    public DbSet<UrlTbl> UrlTbl { get; set; }
}
```

Update your `ApplicationServicesExtension` to:

```cs
public static class ApplicationServicesExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

In your `Program.cs`

```
...
builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();
...
```

Comment: That's not the answer.. Migration tool must create DbContext for its work, but it can't. Answer here: [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation)